# Approximation of chained functions

Tags: regression, bayesian, approximation

Say we want to approximate a set of $n$ continuous functions $f_n(g(x))=y$ where $x \in \mathbb{R}^d, y \in \mathbb{R}, g(x) \in \mathbb{R}^m$ by fitting them to $n$ different datasets $(X, Y)_n$ sampled from $f_n(g(x))=y$ respectively. It's not possible to sample from a function $f_n$ or from the function $g$ directly.

A straightforward way to do this would be to just fit $n$ different models using only data from the respective dataset.

But it seems to be wasteful to discard information from e.g. $(X, Y)_1$ when fitting $f_2(g(x))=y$ as $(X, Y)_1$ contains information about $g$. Would it also be possible to fit $n$ models approximating $f_n$ and one model approximating $g$? How would one go about this? Maybe using some kind of neural network with shared parameters? Maybe there is also a Bayesian approach? Can someone point me to some literature where problems like these are talked about?

I ask because exploiting this kind of known structure seems to be extremely helpful for reducing the amount of needed training data.

Comment: You need to impose some restrictions.  To see why, let $g:\mathbb{R}^d\to Y$ where $Y$ is any set. Given literally any permutations $\sigma:\mathbb{R}^d\to\mathbb{R}^d$ and $\tau:Y\to Y,$ you cannot distinguish $f_n\circ g$ from $f_n\circ \tau\circ g \circ \sigma.$ The best you can hope for, then, would be to estimate some properties of $Y$ by making some assumptions about it.

Comment: @whuber I edited the post to clarify that $g(x) \in \mathbb{R}^m$ Does that make it easier? I also said that the functions are continuous so that they can approximated by e.g a neural network. What other kinds of restrictions would I need to impose? It would be pretty counterintuitive if there were no way to learn something about $g$ by taking a look at the differences of the $(X, Y)_n$ datasets.

Comment: Please take another look at my argument: if you can identify $g$ only modulo composition with another continuous function, what have you learned about it?  The answer is something, but not very much. By applying some mild assumptions, for instance, you might be able to estimate the dimension of its image.

Comment: @whuber I'm afraid I don't get the argument. Let's say $f_1(x) = x$, $f_2(x) = 2x$, $g(x)=x^2$, $\sigma(x) = 0$ and $\tau(x) = 0$. Then it would be very easy to distinguish between $f_n\circ g$ and $f_n\circ \tau\circ g \circ \sigma$ right? The sampled data from $f_1\circ g$ would look like $x^2$, while $f_n\circ \tau\circ g \circ \sigma$ would look like 0.

Comment: You don't get to choose $\sigma$ and $\tau.$  They could literally be *any* bijections.  Together with one putative solution for $g$ they will determine a huge family of other solutions.  Which one of those solutions will you pick?

Comment: @whuber Ah, I see. I would like to choose them so that they minimize the error in the sampled data while generalizing to unseen data. Sry for being unclear. Maybe it's necessary to assume that the $f_n$ functions are from a very narrow family of functions? What tools could then be used to estimate $g$? What if we already have a pretty good guess what $g$ could be?

Comment: That's the right approach: you need to hugely limit the possibilities for the $f_n,$ $g,$ or both so that you can get some *identifiable* information.